# undeclared identifier in C

Tags: c, visual-studio-2012

I am trying to compile a small bank program in C in visual studio 2012 express. It shows me this error "undeclared identifier" for almost all variables and this one too "syntax error: missing ';' before 'type'".Please tell me the correct syntax.Thank you.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
int main()
{
printf("Welcome to skybank\n");
int deposit,withdraw,kbalance;
char option;
printf("Press 1 to deposit cash\n");
printf("Press 2 to Withdraw Cash\n");
printf("Press 3 to Know Your Balance\n");
scanf_s("%c",option);
int decash,wicash;
switch(option)
{
int balance;
printf("Enter your current Balance\n");
scanf_s("%d",&balance);
case 1:
    printf("Enter the amount you want to deposit\n");
    scanf_s("%d",&decash);
    printf("Thank You\n");
    printf("%d have been deposited in your account\n",decash);
    break;
case 2:
    printf("Enter the amount you want to withdraw\n");
    scanf_s("%d",&wicash);
    int wibal;
    wibal=balance-wicash;
    printf("Thank You\n");
    printf("%d have been withdrawed from your account\n",wicash);
    printf("Your balance is %d\n",wibal);
    break;
case 3:
    printf("Your balance is Rs.%d\n",balance);
    break;
default:
    printf("Invalid Input\n");
    break;
}
getchar();
}
```

Comment: in C, You should declare the variables at the beginning of the parent block

Comment: i am still unable to run it.Thank you for your help

Comment: @gkovacs90: Actually, in current C (meaning C11, or even C99), you can declare variables at any point in a block of code.  Only in the 2 decades old C89 wihch is all that's supported by MSVC running as a C compiler is there a problem.  Your diagnosis for the 'undeclared variables' part of the problems with this code is correct in that the MSVC compiler requires variables declared at the start of the block.  Your diagnosis is incorrect in that modern C does not impose this limitation; only the MSVC compiler still does that.  There are other problems in the code.

Comment: Thank you all for your precious time and help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Microsoft C compiler only supports a 25 year old version of the language. And one of the limitations is that all variables must be declared before any other statements. So move all your variable declarations to the top of the function.

The next error I can see is the use of `scanf_s` with the `%c` format string. You must pass a pointer to the variable, and pass the number of characters to read.

```
scanf_s("%c", &option, 1);
```

And likewise you need to pass an address for the read of `balance`.

You also need to change the switch statement so that it just contains cases. Move the bare instructions outside.

Your reading of `option` won't work. Because when you check for `1` you are checking for the character with ASCII code 1. Change `option` to be an `int` and read using `%d`.

Perhaps you are looking for something like this:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int deposit,withdraw,kbalance;
    int option;
    int decash,wicash;
    int balance;
    int wibal;

    printf("Welcome to skybank\n");
    printf("Press 1 to deposit cash\n");
    printf("Press 2 to Withdraw Cash\n");
    printf("Press 3 to Know Your Balance\n");
    scanf_s("%d", &option);
    printf("Enter your current Balance\n");
    scanf_s("%d", &balance);
    switch(option)
    {
        case 1:
            printf("Enter the amount you want to deposit\n");
            scanf_s("%d", &decash);
            printf("Thank You\n");
            printf("%d have been deposited in your account\n", decash);
            break;
        case 2:
            printf("Enter the amount you want to withdraw\n");
            scanf_s("%d", &wicash);
            wibal=balance-wicash;
            printf("Thank You\n");
            printf("%d have been withdrawed from your account\n", wicash);
            printf("Your balance is %d\n", wibal);
            break;
        case 3:
            printf("Your balance is Rs.%d\n", balance);
            break;
        default:
            printf("Invalid Input\n");
            break;
    }
    getchar();
}
```

Comment: it runs but gives me 'invalid input' message immediately after i do anything.

Comment: No it doesn't. It runs fine. Make sure you are pasting the latest version. I had to fix a lot of bugs!

Comment: thank you it worked. you are a genius sir! i remember you had also helped me with my calculator code.

Comment: Yes you can. I think I answered the original question. I think you can move on to the next step yourself. FWIW you might be better off with a real C compiler. On windows try mingw.

Answer (score 1):

do at the beginning of the block in the declaration of the variable for visual c.

E.g.

```
int main()
{
    int deposit,withdraw,kbalance;
    char option;
    int decash,wicash
    int balance;
    int wibal;
...
```

Comment: @user2481364 The What 's you question if it works properly? "tell me the correct syntax."

Comment: it displays the same errors "undeclared variable" and "missing ';' before 'type'.

Comment: @user2481364 it fine(no error) to me. but `int balance, wibal;` move to main bigining.

Comment: It is not a good idea to declare variables at the top of the block following a `switch` statement.  It is syntactically legal, but it is dubious practice at best, and if there were any initializations for the variables, the initializations would not be executed.  This would matter intensely in C++ with complex user-defined types.  It is less of a problem in this code.  But the practice is _bad_ and should not be encouraged.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Yes, certainly. Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the unidentified variables, try putting all declarations of variables at the top of the main block, something like:

```
int main()
{
    int deposit, withdraw, kbalance, decash, wicash, wibal;
    char option;
    printf("Welcome to skybank\n");
```

Older variants of C frown upon mixing variable declarations with code. To my knowledge the C standard of Microsoft's C implementation is pre-C99 so perhaps this could be the issue.

A few other issues that you should look into:

`scanf_s("%c",option);` - `option` should be `&option` as you are taking a pointer to that variable.

Also here: `case 1:`

You want `'1'` (as in `case '1'`) instead of plain `1` as it is a `char`, not an `int` you want.

Same for the other `case` checks.

With regards to the [scanf_s](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE4/en/Scanf_s,_wscanf_s) problems, try compiling with warnings, it should have been pointed out by the compiler.

Finally, you might want to rid your code of the variables you're not using such as `kbalance`, `withdraw` and `deposit`.

Answer (score 0):

try this code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int main()
{
    printf("Welcome to skybank\n");
    int deposit,withdraw,kbalance;
    char option;
    printf("Press 1 to deposit cash\n");
    printf("Press 2 to Withdraw Cash\n");
    printf("Press 3 to Know Your Balance\n");
    scanf("%c",&option);
    int decash,wicash;
    switch(option)
    {
    int balance;
    printf("Enter your current Balance\n");
    scanf("%d",&balance);
    case 1:
        printf("Enter the amount you want to deposit\n");
        scanf("%d",&decash);
        printf("Thank You\n");
        printf("%d have been deposited in your account\n",decash);
        break;
    case 2:
        printf("Enter the amount you want to withdraw\n");
        scanf("%d",&wicash);
        int wibal;
        wibal=balance-wicash;
        printf("Thank You\n");
        printf("%d have been withdrawed from your account\n",wicash);
        printf("Your balance is %d\n",wibal);
        break;
    case 3:
        printf("Your balance is Rs.%d\n",balance);
        break;
    default:
        printf("Invalid Input\n");
        break;
    }
    getchar();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Move this:

```
int balance;
printf("Enter your current Balance\n");
scanf_s("%d",&balance);
```

Before the `switch` statement.

Comment: That is part of the problem; it is not the only problem, or even the most major problem.